# Updater keeps saying Failed to download repository information Check your Internet connection. on 12.10

Tags: 12.10, update-manager

Updater keep saying:

```
Failed to download repository information.
Check your Internet connection.
```

Details:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/screenlets/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found,
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/screenlets/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found,
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/screenlets/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found,
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: I tried changing Download from: Offical and now http://mirror.dattobackup.com/ubuntu but still failed.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me. I went to the software updater setting -> Other Software tab and found those PPAs and removed them.It should work.